# In Apple Music (Big Sur), how can I 'go to current song playing' in the context of the main library?

Tags: itunes, music, shortcut

You used to be able to click <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to highlight the current song in the context of its playlist. However, this doesn't work anymore for songs being played in the library - only when playing from a custom playlist. It will show the song playing in the library but not in the context of the rest of the library. This feature was helpful because it allowed me to look at other songs in proximity to what was playing.

Answer (score 3):

Click <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. This will show you the album that is currently playing. Then click on 'songs' in the sidebar. This will take you to the current song in library view. (What used to be a one-step process is now two steps).

Answer (score -1):

Click on the musical note to the left of Songs in the sidebar. It brings you back to the song list.

Comment: Yes it takes you to the songs view, But does not show the current song in this view.